# Comparar colunas diferentes

Tags: asp.net, gráfico

É possível gerar o gráfico de pizza (pie) comparando colunas diferentes de um `DataTable`?

Ou seja, tenho um `DataTable` com 2 colunas de valores e queria criar um gráfico de pizza para cada linha do `DataTable`, comparando assim os dois valores.

`DataTable`:

```
Descricao | Val1 | Val2
xxxxxxxx  | 9999 | 8888
yyyyyyyy  | 1111 | 2222
```

Estou utilizando o [Microsoft Chart Control](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Samples-Environments-for-b01e9c61), que é nativo do .net

Comment: Sim, é possível. A ideia é desenhar o gráfico completamente do zero? Ou utilizar algo do tipo [.net Charting](http://www.dotnetcharting.com/)?

Comment: @Renan, estou utilizando o [Microsoft Chart Control](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Samples-Environments-for-b01e9c61), que é nativo do .net.

Comment: Edita a pergunta para conter essa informação. Isso aumenta as chances de você conseguir uma boa resposta, ok? E fique com meu upvote adiantado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tem sim. O `DataTable` da Microsoft possuí a facilidade de criar objetos do tipo `DataView`.

Em outras palavras, eles são filtros ou "SELECTS" que você pode fazer dentro de um DataTable. Você pode criar 2 `DataView` para cada tipo de chart que você quer criar e, para cada chart, você seta o `DataSouce` deles para cada `DataView` criado.

A vantagem é que se você adicionar ou modificar informações no DataTable, automaticamente esta modificação é refletida em todos os DataViews existente e, consequentemente, nos seus charts (talvez precisa fazer um rebind, mas nada de muito complidado).